# Remove commas from number field

Tags: lightning, number

I'm new to Salesforce, for the field A which is of datatype number I have to keep the value by  default to "63090050" , however it is displaying as "630,900,50" in the form once I have saved the form, could anyone please suggest me the way out. I have tried all the available  solution ,however it is not getting  displayed as expected "63090050".

Resources which I have referred: [https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000goruAAA#:~:text=Short%20answers%2C%20you%20don%27t.%20Number%20fields%20will%20always,text%2C%20and%20it%20will%20display%20without%20the%20commas](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000goruAAA#:%7E:text=Short%20answers%2C%20you%20don%27t.%20Number%20fields%20will%20always,text%2C%20and%20it%20will%20display%20without%20the%20commas).

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AgyAIAS

Comment: Is this field data actually a number? Like the type you would perform mathematical operations on? Or is it just text, like a postal code?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. **Firstly**, I could more understand it displaying `630,900.50` or `630.500,90`, but not `630,900,50` as you stated. Is there a typo in your question? **Secondly**, do you mean displaying in the UI or does it look like that in the database? (Might be text like Mark Pond said.) **Thirdly**, it would be helpful for us to help you if you listed some of all of the available solutions that you have tried. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/344407/edit) your question to address these three items.

Comment: @MarkPond ,Field A is a number field and I need to keep the field value by default 63090050 , for this Field A , I had created Field B formula dataype Field and referred Field A as TEXT(my_number), however after doing this changes also I'm getting  "630,900,50",once I save the form.

Comment: @Moonpie ,Thank you for welcoming me :), I have to display it as 63090050 , however it is coming as 630,900,50.I have shared the resources which I have tried ,however I'm not getting the expected outcome. Could you please suggest.

Comment: @mark pond , no mathematical operation, it's just like a postal code

Comment: [#1 of 3] I still don't understand how you are getting only two digits to the right of the rightmost comma. I thought It might be truncating one or more digits to the right. In my sandbox, I just tried 9 ways to Sunday to reproduce your issue - all to no avail. I started keeping a chart, but I won't post it, but I tried setting my original field to Number, Currency and Percent types, with various lengths, with 0 or 2 decimal places. Then I created 2 different Formula fields - one of Number type where the formula was just referencing the original field, and one of Text return type where the...

Comment: [#2 of 3] ...formula was `TEXT(original_field__c)`. When the original field was Percent, the Text formula field displayed "630900.5" every other time it displayed "63090050". Never did the Text formula field display with commas. The Number formula field displayed "63,090,050" except when the original field was Percent and it displayed "630,900.50".

Comment: [#3 of 3] **I think that the configuration of one or both of your fields is not what you think it is.** So please edit your question to add the configuration of each of your fields (you can obviously hide/leave out/cover up any sensitive information like _Created By_ or the exact name of the field(s) if necessary). Please include Data Type, Default Value, Length, Decimal Places, Return Type, exact Formula.

Answer (score 2):

If your text field is intended to display a number field's value but without commas, you can use this as the formula for `myTextFormulaField`:
`SUBSTITUTE( TEXT( myNumberField ), "," , ""  )` .
Note that `TEXT(numeric_value_field)` will be a string that is different for different users. It varies according to the User's Locale settings; commas, decimal points, languages etc. Similarly `TEXT(date_value_field)` will vary based on locale settings.